# Is there a way to dynamically change theme in ExtReact?

Tags: extjs, extreact

I know that there is a way to dynamically change the theme in **ExtJS**, by using Fashion of Material theme of modern toolkit.

Is there a way to accomplish this in ExtReact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found it. Since the code to switch theme is provided by Sencha, it should be available at the same position in ExtReact as in ExtJS.

However, in [ExtJS modern kitchen sink](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/examples/kitchensink/?modern#all), you can switch to dark mode like this:

```
Ext.theme.Material.setDarkMode(true)
```

In [ExtReact kitchen sink](https://examples.sencha.com/ExtReact/6.5.0/kitchensink/#/), you cannot:

```
Ext.theme.Material.setDarkMode(true)
Uncaught ReferenceError: Fashion is not defined (ext.js?4ab9c69b8b9cea6d6cdb:1)
    at constructor.hasFashion (ext.js?4ab9c69b8b9cea6d6cdb:1)
    at constructor.setDarkMode (ext.js?4ab9c69b8b9cea6d6cdb:1)
    at <anonymous>:1:20
```